# Swift: How can I get the UItextlabel from headerViewer

Tags: swift, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I need to get the String that is set in the Headerview of a row that I selected. I need this information to decide to what view the row will be send to. I allready have the Row name. But I need aswell the Name of the string I used in the Headerview.

Comment: Do you want to get section header text while tapping on the row ? right ?

Comment: Please put the code to question what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow the steps

1. Take array of section header name like and declare above viewdidload methods

   ```
   let sectionHeaderArray = ["Header1", "Header2"]
   ```
2. implement a method for view for the section header

   ```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) 
   {
       let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
       header.textLabel?.text = self.sectionHeaderArray[section]
   }
   ```
3. in didDeselectRowAtIndexPath method you can get back that section name

   ```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
       let section_name = self.sectionHeaderArray[indexPath.section]
   }
   ```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi Ujesh, Thank you for the answer! I believe I Was not really clear in what I wanted, next time I will put some code in the question. I think youre solution might work aswell. But I did it in an other way. Dirty way ;) I made an extre UILabel in the row, made that label not visible. And assign to that label the value I used in the Header aswell. This way I can read the value in didSelectRowAt, and use in the in the next views.